# Getting limited and sorted pages of items from DynamoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using DynamoDB for one of my react-native projects. Server-side is NodeJS.

The table I have has a primary key '**hashtag**', and a sort key '**timestamp**'.

```
hashtag | timestamp
blabla  | 1
blabla  | 2
blabla  | 3
blabla  | 4
blabla  | 5
```

How would I seperate the table above into pages with limited number of items inside?
The SQL query of the operation would be something like below,

```
"SELECT * FROM TABLENAME ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT STARTFROM, RESULT_PER_PAGE;
```

However, I have no idea how to separate it when using **DynamoDB**. 
I don't want to get all the data at the server by only using 'hashtag' and separate them again and again into pages there, which would be so expensive for my server.

Does anyone have any ideas?

**Note:** I'm trying to see if I can write a feed. Hashtag corresponds to the timeline, and the time stamp is the time of a post. I'm trying to get the last posts in portions in the app as you scroll down. I'm open to any other suggestions. Or should I just go back to using a relational database?

**Edit2:** I believe a play around would be to use the last timestamp I have to get the first five posts that are greater than that timestamp in the same hashtag. Would there be any other ways?

Comment: Have you tried the pagination feature in the SDK? Will that get you where you want to be? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.Pagination

Comment: @Kirk This is pretty much what i had in mind. I didn’t know that it was in the sdk. I’ll check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [pagination feature in the SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.Pagination). That should get you where you want to be.